# Lodash: _.forEach with function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use the lodash [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) method with a nested function that calls a mongo database.

```
var jobs = [];
_.forEach(ids, function(id) {
    JobRequest.findByJobId(id, function(err, result) {
        if(err) callback(err);
        jobs.push(result);
    });
});

callback(null, jobs);
```

I am having problems because the forEach and callbacks will run through before the inner function is ever called. How can I resolve this?

I want the callback to be called after the for each and inner function have completed.

Comment: You should use `async.map`.

Answer (score 12):

One more approach is to wrap everything into promises, in this case job results will be pushed into array in correct order:

```
var promises = ids.map(function(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        JobRequest.findByJobId(id, function (err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(jobs) {
    callback(null, jobs);
}, callback);

// or shorter: Promise.all(promises).then(callback.bind(null, null), callback);
```

Note, that you also need to handle potential situation when `JobRequest.findByJobId` request fails, with promises it's very easy: just pass `callback` as error callback to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Assuming a modern JavaScript engine (or a good polyfill), this is definitely one of the more readable ways to do it!

Answer (score 8):

`JobRequest.findByJobId` is an asynchronous operation. You cannot block asynchronous operations in JavaScript, so you'll need to manually synchronize by counting. Example (error handling omitted for the sake of brevity):

```
var results = [];
var pendingJobCount = ids.length;

_.forEach(ids, function(id) {
    JobRequest.findByJobId(id, function(err, result) {
        results.push(result);
        if (--pendingJobCount === 0) callback(null, results);
    });
});
```

There are, of course, wrapper constructs for doing stuff like this, but I prefer to explain how it actually works. Check out [dfsq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385177/427328) for more details on one of those wrappers, called promises.

Also note that asynchronous operations may complete out of order. The order in the `results` array will not necessarily match the order of the `ids` array. If you need that information connected, you'll need to track it yourself, for example by collecting the results in a map instead of an array:

```
var results = {};
var pendingJobCount = ids.length;

_.forEach(ids, function(id) {
    JobRequest.findByJobId(id, function(err, result) {
        results[id] = result;
        if (--pendingJobCount === 0) callback(null, results);
    });
});
```

This example assumes that there are no duplicates in your `ids` array. Results for duplicate keys would be overridden.

Error handling would work similarly, by inserting additional information into your result. Another example:

```
results.push({id: id, error: null, value: result});
```